# What are the causes of abortive initiation?

Tags: proteins, transcription

I was reading more about DNA transcription, and it mentioned abortive initiation. The article gave no explanation as to why the phenomenon occurs.

The only explanation I can think of is that it is an error in the "machinery" of the RNA polymerase.

Is there any scientific research as to why abortive initiation occurs?

Comment: What article did you read? Did you read [wiki > abortive initiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortive_initiation) also?

Comment: @Remi.b The Wikipedia article is one of the articles I read. I also read https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2563432/